# apphud sdk and completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm using the apphud sdk to fetch in app purchase products. The SDK is used to purchase products in an IOS app. I use the following code

```
Apphud.paywallsDidLoadCallback { paywalls in
if let paywall = paywalls.first(where: { $0.identifier == "your_paywall_id" }) {
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot pass function of type '([ApphudPaywall]) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
```

paywallsDidLoadCallback is defined as

```
@MainActor
@objc public static func paywallsDidLoadCallback(_ callback: @escaping ([ApphudPaywall]) -> Void) {
    ApphudInternal.shared.performWhenOfferingsReady {
        callback(ApphudInternal.shared.paywalls)
    }
}
```

is this because the apphud sdk does not support async/await? Since this is a third party sdk, is there a quick fix? Please help!

Comment: There is no async declaration in the code you have shown. Perhaps you can edit your question to show the code in a broader context? Are you calling it in an async function?  The general approach for wrapping closure based callback APIs in async/await is to use `withCheckedContinuation`

Comment: @Paulw11 oh my god. You solved it. Thanks so much. withCheckedContinuation is the problem. Can you tell me more about withCheckedContinuation? or I can google it. Thanks for helping me! You are a god send as always!